# Stein Kernel for nonzero mean

Tags: probability, statistics

For a random variable $X$ with mean $0$ the stein Kernel $T$ (which is also a random variable) is defined as
\begin{equation}
E[Xf(X)]= E[Tf'(X)]
\end{equation}

However this can be generalized to a random variable $X$ with mean $\theta$ as follows: Suppose $T_{X-\theta}$ is a stein kernel of $X - \theta$ then
\begin{align}
E[(X - \theta)f(X)] &= E[(X-\theta)f((X- \theta) + \theta)]\\
&= E[T_{X-\theta}f'((X - \theta) + \theta)\\
&= E[T_{X-\theta} f'(X)]
\end{align}

I'm confused by the step $E[(X-\theta)f((X- \theta) + \theta)]= E[T_{X-\theta}f'((X - \theta) + \theta)$. I know from definition of a stein kernel on a random variable with mean $0$: $E[(X-\theta)f(X- \theta)]= E[T_{X-\theta}f'(X - \theta)]$, but the added $\theta$ in the argument of $f$ throws me off. It seems like maybe they are conditioning on $\theta$ but I can't quite see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a name to the function. Let $U = X-\theta$, you will have

$$E[Ug(U)] = E[T_Ug'(U)]$$ for every $g$. Now for a function $f$, let $g(u) = f(u+\theta)$ so $f(x) = g(x-\theta)$ and $f'(x) = g'(x-\theta)$. Finally

$$E[(X-\theta) f(X)] = E[Ug(U)] = E[T_Ug'(U)] = E[T_{X-\theta} f'(X)]$$